# How to load websites from a list alternately to browser

Tags: javascript, python, bash

I have a monitor in my office and I need to display different graphs from different sources. There is `index1.html`, `index2.html` and  `index3.html`.

Each html page uses different css files as the html files loads different iframes with different graphs and iframe sizes.

I would like to have a script that loads `index1.html` and after 60 seconds loads `index2.html` and again after 60 seconds load `index3.html` to the browser.

This can run till user kills the script. How can I achieve this? Would you recommend python or bash script, or JavaScript?

```
while(true){

firefox index1.html

sleep 60

#DISPLAY=:0.0 wmctrl -c "Firefox"

firefox index2.html

sleep 60

#DISPLAY=:0.0 wmctrl -c "Firefox"

firefox index3.html

sleep 60

#DISPLAY=:0.0 wmctrl -c "Firefox"

}
```

Comment: Have you thought about having the html pages redirect to the next one without involving a shell script?

Comment: "Would you recommend python or bash script, or JavaScript?" isn't this the textbook definition of "Primarily opinion based"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need this functionality in UI only you can use **setInterval** from **javascript** to achieve what you need, I have implemented a simple example here. Let me know if you need any mode detail.

For complete working solution clone this repo.

GIT URL: https://github.com/helloritesh000/how-to-load-websites-from-a-list-alternately-to-browser

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<body>

<iframe id="ifrm" src="" width="300" height="300"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var arraySites = ["index3.html", "index2.html", "index1.html"];
    var counter = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){ var url = arraySites.pop(); console.log(url); LoadIframe(url);} , 10*1000);


function LoadIframe(arrIndex)
{
    if(arrIndex != null && arrIndex != undefined && arrIndex != '')
        document.getElementById('ifrm').src = arrIndex;
    else
        clearInterval(interval);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could do this. Python has [a built-in module called `webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) that will open a file or URL in your default web browser:

```
import webbrowser
import time

filelist = ["index1.html", "index2.html", "index3.html"]
for file in filelist:
    webbrowser.open(file,new=2)
    time.sleep(60)
```

I just tried this by replacing `filelist` with the full paths to some local HTML files, and it worked for me.

If you wanted to use a browser other than the default one, you can set that up too. For example:

```
firefox_path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
webbrowser.register('firefox', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(firefox_path), 1)
webbrowser.get('firefox').open("index.html", new=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python should work for you.
If you could store the file names in a list and then iterate over it using `time.sleep()` it would work perfectly.

```
import webbrowser
import os
import time

# Replace the absolute_path with actual ABSOLUTE PATH of the file
file_list = ["absolute_path/index1.html","absolute_path/index2.html","absolute_path/index3.html"]
while (True):
    for a_file in file_list:
        webbrowser.open('file://' + os.path.realpath(a_file))
        time.sleep(60) # 60 seconds delay
    file_list = [] # Empty file_list in order to avoid opening infinite tabs
```

Hope this answers your question!!!

Comment: Hi, thank you. Unfortunately the loop will end with the last element in the list and the browser will open new tabs infinity.

Comment: @TonyTony It will open the number of tabs you want it to open. If you put 100 items in list it will open 100 tabs. Isn't that what u want.

Comment: I need to run my script infinitely like here https://pastebin.com/8ehSSK8Y. With this solution i would get an infinity number of tabs open. Instead i need just 3 tabs open with index1.html, index2.html, index3.html

Comment: In that case you just need to populate only these 3 html files in your list and enclose this for loop in an infinite loop

Comment: Edited the solution @TonyTony. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using javascript and jquery.

```
<div id="content">

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#content").load("index1.html");
});

var counter = 1;
var i = setInterval(function(){
    switch(counter){
    case 0:
    $("#content").load("index1.html");
    break;
    case 1:
    $("#content").load("index2.html");
    break;
    case 2:
    $("#content").load("index3.html");
    break;
    }

    counter++;
    if(counter == 3) {
        counter = 0;
    }
}, 60000);
</script>
```

I hope this is useful

Answer (score 0):

You can make an iframe that takes up the whole page, and use a recursive JS function to iterate through all report pages forever.

Just update the **frames** array to add/remove pages, adjust your timing with the second parameter of the **setTimeout** function

```js
function updateFrames(i)
    {
        var frames = ['https://example.org/index1.html', 'https://example.org/index2.html', 'https://example.org/index3.html'];
        document.getElementById('iframe').src = frames[i];

        i++; if (i >= frames.length) { i = 0 };

        setTimeout(function(){
            updateFrames(i);
        }, 60000);
    }
    window.onload = updateFrames(0);
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe" style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw;" src=""></iframe>
```